# css animation disappeared when the first one was finished

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-animations

I have a button that when I click it, it makes an animation for an image to move up.

Every-time I click the button, it should add another image that moves up.

The problem is: If I have tapped the button more than one time, the first one completes, but all the other images just disappears before reaching the point.

***css***

```
.zoom{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1%;
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: zoom 2s ease forwards;
    z-index: 2;

}

@keyframes zoom{
    0%{opacity: 0}
    50%{opacity: 1}
    100%{opacity: 0; top: 1%;}
}
```

***html***

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
          <div class="col-lg-4 item-info">

             <div class="card" style="background-color: #05008F">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="image.png" width="640" height="360">
             </div>

             <div class="box-element">
                <button>Image Up</button>
             </div>

          </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $("button").on("click", function() {
           $(this).closest(".item-info")
               .find("img")
               .clone()
               .addClass("zoom")
               .appendTo("body");
           setTimeout(function(){
               $(".zoom").remove();
           }, 2000);
       });
    </script>
</body>
```

The animation comes from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQhR5RbJ2sk)

clicking the button more than 1 time, should show more than 1 image going up.

---

**The problem is:**

When I click many times during the 2 seconds, the images are displayed, but when the 2 seconds are gone from the first click, all of the images disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that on the timeout all the .zoom images are removed.

This snippet 'remembers' which img is to be removed on each timeout.

It is important in a practical situation that these images are removed when no longer needed else you could eventually run out of store.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .zoom {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      right: 1%;
      width: 5%;
      height: 5%;
      opacity: 0;
      animation: zoom 2s ease forwards;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    @keyframes zoom {
      0% {
        opacity: 0
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        top: 1%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-lg-4 item-info">

    <div class="card" style="background-color: #05008F">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1084/640/360?grayscale" width="640" height="360">
    </div>

    <div class="box-element">
      <button>Image Up</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").on("click", function() {
      const thisImg = $(this).closest(".item-info")
        .find("img")
        .clone();
      thisImg.addClass("zoom")
        .appendTo("body");
      setTimeout(function() {
        thisImg.remove();
      }, 2000);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
       
           $(this).closest(".item-info")
               .find("img")
               .clone()
               .addClass("zoom")
               .appendTo("body");
           if(!$('.zoom').get(0) )
           setTimeout(function(){
               $(".zoom").remove();
           }, 2000);
       });
```

Try it this way and tell if everythins is ok :)

Comment: Still not working, I tap it, then I tap again, the second one is not showing up.

Comment: I want to be able to show more than 1 at the same time.

Comment: check it again after edit

Comment: The problem with this, if you do opacity 1 at 100%, you will see it's staying there. But anyways this is good, now they don't disappear at the same time.

Comment: I solved this by doing like this `@keyframes zoom{
    0%{opacity: 0}
    50%{opacity: 1}
    80%{opacity: 0; top: 1%;}
    100%{opacity: 1; top: -100%}
}`

Comment: But since they will stay there, maybe it will make the page lagging, if you have tapped 1 million times, but hopefully it will never happen.

Comment: This solution can work visually but you do need to remove the img once it is no longer needed as the original did (although it removed too many at once).